# Was the electric fence on Roku San sabotaged?

Tags: character-motivation, starship-troopers

In "Starship Troopers 3: Marauder", the bugs were able to overrun the compound on Roku San because the entire power grid for the electric fence went down. This was apparently despite redundancies in place to prevent such an occurrence.

**SOLDIER:** *(in background) Electrical system malfunction.* It's all down! Everything!

**HAUSER:** The fence...

**BECK:** How could that have happened?

This leads to a series of events that results in several characters - including Sky Marshall Anoke - crashed & stranded on the planet OM-1 where the bug "emperor" resides. During conversation with the creature, it is revealed that

> the Sky Marshall has come under the emperor bug's psychic influence and believes it to be God.

**Was Sky Marshall Anoke responsible for the fence going down on Roku San, and if so, how did he know that he would end up on OM-1?**